# Corporation Troubles: are the different corporation HQ versions actually different in any significant way?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

At the end of the Corporation Troubles plot, I was offered to buy a corporate headquarters for myself. Before I can get the station, though, I must choose 1 out of 3 styles. Is it only a cosmetic difference, or are the 3 choices different? Perhaps they have different numbers of docking slots for my ships?

Answer (score 1):

Difference is purely cosmetic.

It is not another Player Head Quarters, it is more like big Equipment Dock. You will not be able produce ships in it, or store ST cargo.

Slots number differs between Argon (HQ plot) and Terran Head Quarters (Loose Ends plot) from, Terran HQ is bigger.

[image]
Image from http://roguey.co.uk/x3ap/help/guides/corporation-troubles/page12.php

Comment: Do you have a source for the 3 corpodate HQs being functionally identical? The models were made years ago, so the devs had no reason to make them equal.

Comment: No sources, just wild guess. Random googling did not find any sources to prove or disprove this. You can save before choosing reward and check if you have enough big ships.

Comment: personally I think the strong arms one looks the most badass.  That's the one I went for.

Comment: I choose it too, so and roguey in his guide. look like it is popular choice.